# How to rotate only one element in a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIView which contains many items like UIScrollView.

How can I specify I want to rotate **only one** UIScrollView when I change the position of my device (or iPhone Simulator) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- return NO from

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

- handle the device rotation notification yourself:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

- and rotate just the view you want:

```
self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
```

Comment: I tried to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation() and it's working fine. I'm not sure I understood how to handle myself the rotation notification, but I guess using this method won't allow me to keep rotation effects on my element ?

Comment: Since you only want one thing to rotate, you need to tell the "system" that your view controller does not rotate, or else you'll get all elements rotating, that's what returning "NO" is for.   But then, how do you know when the device rotates?   That's what handling the notification is for, it tells you when to rotate.

Comment: Ok, I understood that. But when shall I call the notification ? When the devices rotates, right. But how do I detect the rotation of the device ? Thanks.

Comment: No, you *receive* the notification when the device rotates.  How do you expect to know when the device rotates yourself? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *localView = [mainView viewWithTag:tagOfScrollViewToRotate];   
 UIInterfaceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

            float   angle;
            switch (deviceOrientation) {
                case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                {   
                    angle = M_PI;
                    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                    [localView setTransform:transform];

                    break;
                }
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                {
                    angle = -M_PI/2;
                    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                    [localView setTransform:transform];
                    localView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

                    break;
                }
                case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                {
                    angle = M_PI/2;
                    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                    [localView setTransform:transform];
                    localView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    angle = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Good luck, :D